# Keep getting 'false' only when using POST

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "matchDB.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: { 
              "username": $("#username").val(), 
              "password": $("#password").val() 
          },
          success: function(data) {
              $("#display").html(data.lastLoginStatus);
          }
});
```

Here is my matchDB.php

```
$sql = "SELECT date_format(lastLogin, '%m/%d/%y') AS dateTime,
               lastLoginStatus
          FROM fp_login
         WHERE username = :username
           AND password = :password";

$np = array();
$np[":username"] = $_POST["username"];
$np[":password"] = sha1($_POST["password"]);

$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute($np);

$record = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($record);
```

It works when I use GET, and I pass the parameters through the URL to test, but it keeps returning 'false' when I use POST.

On a side note, is there an easier way to pass POST parameters to test besides an HTML form?

Any help is appreciated, as I am clearly a textbook noob.

Comment: You should change `type` to `method`, you can read more here --> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: So, props for using PDO and prepared statements, but don't use `sha1` to hash your passwords. Use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead

Comment: @mendez7 they are aliases of each other. Was `type` for many years and `method` was only added in recent years but they point to same functionality

Comment: *"Is there an easier way?"*. Use a REST client app like Postman. Some IDE's also have them built in

Comment: Can you show an example of the *working* `GET` request? How are you running your PHP server? If you're using PHPStorm, I've seen previous issues with its built-in server not accepting POST data.

Comment: any output of `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`?